# Is there a way to dispose an Arduino String() to free memory?

Tags: string, memory, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

Is there a way to dispose an Arduino String-Object, so the memory it uses gets freed up, when the String is not needed anymore?

I didn't find a function in the reference for this, and when I call free(&str), an Exception is thrown.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Simon

Edit:
I code with the Arduino-IDE, like this

```
void setup() {
  // a few setup things
}

void loop() {
  String str1 = "some json String";
  String str2 = str1.substring(10);
  String str3 = jsonRemoveWhiteSpace(str2);
  // so at this point I'd like to dispose of str1 and str2 to free up the memory, 
  // because the strings are also quite long json strings.
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where it's declared and used? The canonical way to retrieve memory from objects in C++ is to let them go out of scope.

Comment: `free` is used as the complement to `malloc`. You shouldn't be using `malloc` in C++.

Comment: @JohnFilleau alright, thanks for the information, thats good to know.

Comment: use only one String object

Comment: Don't use `String` at all.  It's bloated, wasteful, and slow.  Use regular C strings and declare them statically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curly braces to make explicit scopes. The C++ standard requires that objects declared in a scope are destroyed when they go out of scope. For objects that manage dynamic memory (such as `String`) that means the dynamic memory will be released to the system.

```
void loop() {
  String str3;
  {
    // explicit scope begins here...

    String str1 = "some json String";
    String str2 = str1.substring(10);

    str3 = jsonRemoveWhiteSpace(str2);

    // ...and ends here
  }
  // at this point str1 and str2 go out of scope, and are destroyed
  // str3 was declared outside of the scope, so is fine
}
```

If it doesn't affect the variable naming too much, you can consider assigning the result of `substring` and `jsonRemoveWhiteSpace` to the `String` you're operating on. The assignment operator for `String` is well behaved and releases memory as expected.

```
String str = "some json String";
str = str.substring(10);
str = jsonRemoveWhiteSpace(str);
```

or

```
String str = "some json String";
str = jsonRemoveWhiteSpace(str.substring(10));
```

Comment: @s137, it will speed up memory fragmentation and you will run out of heap faster. don't use String

Comment: @Juraj I know, the problem here is I have to use String, because the library I am using expects a String-Object.

Comment: it is in your answer. so that is OK